# Problem with json serialization and fetch values

Tags: json, swift, serialization

I have data in JSON and I want to fetch data from structure like below - I want to get time value, in this case String: "04:35:00" and append all this time-values to my Hours model.

```
{
"result": [
    {
        "values": [
            {
                "value":"null",
                "key":"symbol_2"

            },
            {
                "value":"null",
                "key":"symbol_1"},
            {
                "value":"016",
                "key":"company"

            },
            {
                "value":"QUW12DO",
                "key":"direction"

            },
            {
                "value":"TD-4WYS",
                "key":"road"

            },
            {
                "value":"04:35:00",
                "key":"time"

}]},
```

//by code like this:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in



        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

            print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "result")!)

            if let stopsArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "result") as? NSArray {

                    for stop in stopsArray{


                        if let stopDict = stop as? NSDictionary {


                            let hours = stopDict.value(forKey: "time")

                            let myModel = Hours(hours: hours as? String)
                            self.list.append(myModel)
                            print("LIST: \(self.list)")

                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                self.actInd.stopAnimating()
                                self.actInd.isHidden = true
                                self.containerLittle.isHidden = true
                                self.loadingView.isHidden = true
                            }
                        }
                    }

            }
        }
    }).resume()
```

On this moment when I append my code to model I have nill everywhere. How to fetch time value to model?

Comment: First - don't use `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` in Swift. Use a proper Swift dictionary and array. Fix that first and things will be a lot easier.

Comment: There is no `"time"` key in your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have more complicated structure of JSON. Your JSON is Array of Dictionaries that contain Array of Dictionaries. Try this code:

```
    typealias JSONDict = Dictionary<String, Any>
    typealias JSONArray = Array<Any>

    if let result = jsonObj?["result"] as? JSONArray {
        for case let value as JSONDict in result {
            if let values = value["values"] as? JSONArray {
                for case let value as [String : String] in values {
                    if let timeString = value["value"], value["key"] == "time" {
                        // Create your Hours model
                        print(timeString)

                        // Use break only if you have single "time" member in "values" array
                        //break
                    }
                }

                // Use break only if you have single "values" member in "result" array
                //break
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah men, you made my day!  I only remove `break` and myModel contains all what i need. Thanks!

Comment: @Moritz you are right about value(forKey:) method. It's just a typo from my side. I've replaced it with object(forKey:) method, thanks. What else errors do you see? This code works fine in Playground and provides the correct result.

Comment: @Moritz I've done some refactor, now it looks more like Swift way.